# MySQL query time grows exponentially when data in TEXT column grows linearly

Tags: mysql, performance

We have a table that currently has a TEXT column and the length of the column averages at about 2,000 characters. We wanted to see what the performance of queries that select that column would be if the average was 5k, 10k, 20k etc.

We set up an isolated test and found that as the length of the TEXT column increased linearly, the query time increased exponentially.

Anyone have any quick thoughts on why this might be. Can provide more info but pretty straight forward.

Comment: Have you used a full text index in combination with `match against`. This is the recommended way the search text columns.

Comment: We aren't searching within the TEXT column, just selecting it. SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.id < 50; etc

Comment: SELECT * is very bad form, only select the fields that you really need. Because you are (potentially) sending lots of unneeded data across the wire. Also if you're using InnoDB you're killing the opportunity of using covering indexes, also note @Mchl's answer.

Comment: @Dan.StackOverflow: can you provide more details on the results you had (sizes, times, etc) and the table's structure (number of rows, total size of a record, indexes)?

Comment: @Jonah, there are only two columns, and we wouldn't have a TEXT column if we didn't need it, of course we want SELECT *. We are using MyISAM, not InnoDB. ypercube, will add more info shortly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for that could be because `TEXT` and `BLOB` fields are not stored alongside with all other 'regular' fields, so that database engine actually needs to pull these from another area of disk.

We'd need to see your query Is it just a lookup by ID field, or do you search in `TEXT` field? In the latter case as average length of stored text increases, so does the amount of data for the database to process <s>and it grows exponentially.</s>

Comment: ... no it's not exponential... I was wrong about that. Imagined something else in my mind, but when started calculating it, it's still linear ;P

Comment: Our isolated test is a table with 2 columns: an id and a TEXT column. Our query is selecting from the table by id in increments of 50. So say it has 1000 rows we'll do 0 < id < 50, 50 < id < 100, 100 < id < 150 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can select only these fields that you want to view using `limit`:

```
SELECT field1, f2, f3 FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,30
```

For the next 30 rows do

```
SELECT field1, f2, f3 FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 30,30
```

You can never read 10k rows in one go anyway, this will make your selects much much faster.

Answer (score 0):

this is related to how many data can mysql read during a disk read cycle,
and how many data can be sent over the network in a data sending cycle

when data size growth, more overheads will be on

- disk-read cycle (mysql spent more time on record seeking)
- data-sending (require more cycle to allow data transfer over the network)

not all data are stored in memory especially on text and blob,
mysql need to found the data from disk,
and transfer back to the clients

in another words, mysql index is fast,
because it does not required disk read

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wild guess, but this might be a low level implementational issue, MySql doesn't expect you to retrieve so much data at once so it has to reallocate a bigger block of memory for its internal use and copy data from the old location to the new one and repeat this over and over again as the data grows, this is the only thing that comes to my mind that can explain the query time going up exponentially while the data grows linearly. Your solution is to limit the amount of data you retrieve at once.